# Hand drawn sketchy symbology styles for GIS software

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, symbology, style

Often times in planning projects, a hand drawn, sketchy look is desirable in order to convey the preliminary nature of a project.

Is anyone aware of any utilities/plugins for desktop GIS software (ArcGIS, QGIS etc.) that enable the user to apply a hand drawn, sketchy look to feature symbology without modifying the geometry?

Here is a product called M-Color for AutoCAD that does the sort of thing that I am looking for but it is of course CAD centric:

http://www.m-color.com/m-color/flash/hand_drawn.html

This sort of thing can also be achieved in SketchUp using styles. The best solution would be one that would eliminate intermediate steps, allowing the user to stay in a single software environment and avoid any intermediate export/import steps.

Answer (score 10):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
> because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
> and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
> should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
> type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
> site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
> to do so by editing this answer.

---

## QGIS

Asger Petersen shared some [pencil line styles](https://github.com/AsgerPetersen/qgis_styles/tree/master/pencil_styles) for QGIS v3.x. They are:

> Based on marker line with random displacements from a normal
> distribution.

[image]

## MapBox

In 2014, MapBox released a style called [Pencil](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/pencil-drawn-style/) to emulate hand-drawn base maps. They mentioned the style was based on real hand-drawn lines. Paper textures were also added to achieve nice effects:

[image]

## Bing

Looking at the past, in 2010 Microsoft published [Destination Maps](https://www.instantfundas.com/2010/06/bing-destination-maps-creates-cool-hand.html), an on-line utility to automatically generate map sketches, allowing users to indicate how to access a certain point.

[image]

Everything seems to go back to [Agrawalas's work](http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/routemaps/) (2001) on generalization and distortion of route maps for improving usability.

[image]

It would be marvelous to have similar styles in GIS software. I think distorted maps would be more a sort of image product, not something to interact with. I remember that generating a destination map used to take a while on the Microsoft platform.

Answer (score 4):

After searching a lot all over the internet for a  solution to this I made my own DIY sketch style.

This is the result (see the building layer):

[image]

To create this style I did do the following steps:

1 - Export the vector layer to excel (or just create a CSV file that you can join with the layer). Give every object a random number from 0 to 1 ( in excel =RANDBETWEEN(0;1000)/1000 )

2 - Import the csv and join it to the original layer

3 - Set the first symbol layer to a gradient fill with a dark color to a greyish semitransparent color. In the example I did use a radial fill. Then I did set the first reference points x-value to the random number assigned to the polygon and the second reference points y values to 1- the random number. This is to create the random feeling of a sketch (all strokes are different).

4 - Add a second symbol layer on top of the first one. This one you set to a shapeburst fill where the outer color is transparent white and the inner color is white. Set shading style to "Shade to a set distance" with a value that is the desired width of the "strokes". In the example I did use 0,35 mm.

5 - Enjoy. I have noticed that the strokes can be hard to see when you are working with the project (graphic bug). But when exported to a map the style is working great.

I just came up with this solution so there is certainly a lot of adjustment that can be made to make it look better.

Answer (score 1):

there is vector action pack [here](http://graphicriver.net/item/3d-sketcher-vector-actions-pack/667283) for photoshop, maybe it works who want to convert their symbology to vector art....it is only $5.. there is video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNCuJO54b8k), about how can use it..

[image: sketch]